# Steps involved in reading an xml file from webservice .NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-services

I would like to know what are the basic steps involved in setting up your application to able to read data from another application. Then take that data and modify it and send it back to the application.
The data being read will have over 100 fields.... what is the most efficent way to store them? Put them in a class object?

I know web services are involved...any other info would be great!

The application is in .NET using vb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be more specific about your requirements to get a truly useful answer.  That said, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is likely to make your life much easier.  Google for tutorials -- I can't say I have a favorite.  You can handle one- or two-way communication readily with WCF, and you can then focus more on making your application logic work.